# php, infinite loop in while() loop

Tags: php, while-loop, infinite-loop

```
/// infinite loop??
$x=1; 
while($x=9){ 
echo $x;
$x++;
}
```

i dont understand the reason behind, why the above code causes infinite loop
in my opinion above code should output "9" once. but it outputs endless 999999999......

at first (when x is equal to 1) while statement is false so nothing happens, 
then x becomes 2 but again while statement is false;

So when x becomes 9 while statement is true so it should echo 9 then we add 1 due to x++; and it becomes 10 so while statement becomes false but as i see it doesnt because

it continues to echo 9999999.......

pls enlighten me regarding the above code. best regards.

note:i have checked the similar questions but cant find the answer for my situation thx

Comment: For this reason, you will see it written if (9 == $x) in many cases, to avoid such errors.

Comment: I think you should have assumed something was wrong from the very first moment when your x=9 made it into the while loop. If the while condition is false then $x++ wouldn't even have ran all.

Answer (score 10):

`$x=9` is an assignment, and is always true. Perhaps you meant `$x==9`, or some other relational operator.

Answer (score 3):

You mean

```
$x == 9
```

But in your example it won't do anything, because $x != 9. You probably mean

```
while($x < 9)
```

Comment: Old thread, but in case someone reads it. 

The
But in your example it won't do anything, because $x != 9. You probably mean

while($x < 9)

is untrue. If he DOES write $x == 9, then the loop while stop as soon as $x becomes 9. So it will output 123456789 and then stop.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the value of 9 to the variable x instead of performing a relational comparison. A common mistake. = is the assignment operator whereas == is the equality comparison operator.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)#Assignment_versus_equality